# When do the Tier 17 world bosses respawn?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Well I'm trying to gear up my alts by killing the world bosses out in the world but usually they aren't even there. I'm not sure if I miss them just by a couple of minutes or if they take hours to respawn.

What are the Respawn timers on The T17 World bosses? (Drov and Tarlna)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drov and Tarlna respawn quickly - "**about 15 minutes**" seems to be the most quoted respawn time.

However, **only one of those two bosses will be active** at any time! On days that Drov is respawning, Tarlna cannot be found, and vice versa.

*Tip: Check whether LFR shows an existing raid for one of those bosses and, if so, join that raid.*